# How to embed web form in email

Tags: html, forms, gmail, html-email

I am looking for solution which need to be address to **embed web form in email**. My requirement is need to provide a web form in email, so that user can enter required data like name,phone number,address and need to provide upload file component also. He can upload required documents like driving licence or rental agreement through upload file button.

I am not getting any solution for this. Can you please any one give suggestions to implement this requirement.

Answer (score 4):

basically you can use html inside your emails but

1. clients that are not able to display html tags will not display your form
2. even if client will display you cannot be sure how it will look like
3. even if client will display form correctly usually it will not allow you to send the form or will display a warning that user is sending something - this can be very demotivating and give user bad feeling

basically - don't use form in email - use link to the site with a form